# Garbage Collection .Net

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I think I've got a basic understanding of the way the Garbage Collector works in .Net but recently I was asked a question which I didn't really understand. From what I can remember the question was asked along the lines of -

> Taking into account the different generations involved in Garbage
>   Collection, what generation would you like your objects to be in?

I took a guess and said generation 0 because this would mean a short lived object and would free up memory. The flip side to this though is when I was going through some MSDN documentation it indicated that Generation 2 objects are more stable (i.e. long lived) and I know the GC collects this less frequently.

What's the correct answer to this or is it another 'It depends' answer?

Comment: "what generation would you like your objects to be in". Actually I can't even imagine a reason I would care in which gen my objects are...

Comment: I think (generally speaking) if this question matters to you, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I would say - not generations itself are important but the proportion between their usage. If I am to track GC usage, I start from seeing how those proportions looks.

Comment: Was this an interview question, an exercise in a book/class, or a rhetorical question?  Only the last one really makes much sense; the other two tend to cause facepalms.

Comment: @Adriano I agree, this was what kind of threw me! I'd never really thought about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is, of course, "the *right* generation". If an object is short-lived, I would like it to be in the generation optimized for short-lived objects. If my object is long-lived, I would like it to be in the generation optimized for long-lived objects.

If there was one "best" generation for all objects, we'd make that the default and do away with the others. The GC creators will be pleased to hear that, generationality is a source of much complexity in their algorithms ;-)

Comment: I don't thing the long-lived objects matter at all, they will be pushed to the 2nd generation after two collections anyway. I think the purpose of this question was that it is nice if the short-lived objects don't make it to higher generations.

Comment: To be fair, the GC creators added that complexity themselves.  :)  GC doesn't *have* to be generational, and didn't start out that way.

Comment: @cHao Evidence so far suggest that they *do* have to be generational... *if* they want to perform better ;-)

Comment: @Grzenio You mention that they'll be pushed to a higher generation soon because that's the best generation for them to be in! There is a difference between "I'd like this object to be in gen x" and "I'd like to immediately allocate this object in gen x". It's indeed nice if objects aren't promoted out of the nursery immediately before dying, but it's equally important that long-lived objects don't pollute the nursery.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit weird question. I would answer generation 0 as well, because the generation 0 collections are by far the cheapest and so the overhead of the GC is the smallest. I think the purpose of this question was that it is nice if the short-lived objects don't make it to higher generations. Long-lived ones will make it to the last generation anyways.

Comment: They're the cheapest because most objects aren't in there. If you force all your objects in there, you lose all benefits and gain some new downsides along the way.

Comment: @delnan, I don't think the question is about 'forcing' anything, it is more about observing which object are where based on the current algorithms in the GC.

Comment: Perhaps "force" is the wrong term. My point is, you *don't* want all objects to be in gen0: You only want the very-short-lived ones in gen0, and every object that lives longer should get the hell out of the nursery.

Comment: @Grzenio: Even so, if you had a preference for generation 0 and "optimized" your allocations so that most of your objects were short-lived and small, the end result is a lot more objects in that generation.  But then gen-0 collections would actually slow down, for the same reason there are generations in the first place.